# how to export private key in AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

In AWS, I want to export a file. I followed this [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/acm/latest/userguide/gs-acm-export-private.html). For me,
it looks like below,

[image]

How to enable this option and download the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Export (private certificates only)` is only valid when you use [AWS Certificate Manager Private Certificate Authority](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/acm-pca/latest/userguide/PcaWelcome.html) (ACM Private CA), not the regular ACM. Private certificates **can't be exported** from ACM, only from ACM Private CA.

However, unlike ACM which is free, ACM Private CA is **very expensive** ($400.00/month + other fees) and they are only for private use (not the internet):

> Certificates issued by a private CA are trusted only within your organization, **not on the internet**.

Thus if you want to have control over private key of your public certificate, you have to create one yourself and then [import it into ACM](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/acm/latest/userguide/import-certificate.html). Don't confuse `ACM` with `ACM Private CA`.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have configured a wildcard domain on AWS route 53. I want to get  private key wildcard certificate for the wildcard domain. Currently I can see `CNAME` in the domain. How to get the file?

Comment: @MohamedThasinah No problem. Certs from ACM can be used only on load balancer, CloudFront distro and API Gateway. You can't get their private keys. You have to use a third party service to generate new keys. Popular choice is https://letsencrypt.org/ which generates free public SSL certificates.

Answer (score 1):

u can generate certification's info by aws cli:

step 1:

get certs listed in your acm:

```
ubuntu@amirio:~/$ aws acm list-certificates 
{
    "CertificateSummaryList": [
        {
            "CertificateArn": "arn:aws:acm:ca-central-1:71****789:certificate/*****cc208b",
            "DomainName": "*****.com"
        }
    ]
}
```

step 2:

get certificates:

```
aws acm get-certificate --certificate-arn arn:aws:acm:ca-central-1:71****789:certificate/*****cc208b
```

output should be same as:

> {
> "Certificate": "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\nM .... mN9ti3m+9oqPIA==\n-----END
> CERTIFICATE-----\n",
> "CertificateChain": "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\nMII8mYtWDTANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQsF\nADA5MQswCQYDVQQGEwJSlQOYiypok1JR4U\nakcjMS9cmvqtmg5iUaQqqcT5NJ0hGA==\n-----END
> CERTIFICATE-----\n-----BEGIN
> CERTIFICATE-----\nMIIEdTCCA12gAwDAwMDBaFw0zNDA2MjgxNzM5MZ3/VyVOEVqQdZe4O/Ui5GjLIAZHYcSNPYeehu\nVsyuLAOQ1xk4meTKCRlb/weWsKh/NEnfVqn3sF/tM+2MR7cwA130A4w=\n-----END
> CERTIFICATE-----" }

Comment: The output is not the private key though, right? The certificate file is the equivalent of the public key.